# With JavaScript is it possible to Read/Write from/to a file on the server

Tags: javascript, json, flat-file

I have a series of JSON Objects I want to save locally on my server. I am attempting to avoid any server-side script like PHP as required per demand of whats being built. I know its a security risk, but that in this case is not a particular worry. So that said is it possible to actually write to a file and or get its contents via javascript with or without the help of a lib such as jquery?

I should mention I am attempting to avoid ActiveX as I know this is an IE only feature and the software we are developing is planned to be Cross Browser supported

Comment: You'll have to use AJAX (however you do it - jQuery, vanilla JS, etc), and a little bit of server side scripting; the file won't write itself.

Comment: I know through Server Side like PHP or ASP or something to the effect there of (other than ActiveX) I can do it, hell I wouldn't be asking here if it were that simple. I have a demand however to avoid server side script if and at all where ever possible. So that said I need to know through and through 100% that this is not possible via JavaScript alone before I am allowed to say ok I have to do it this way in regards to the PHP or similar.

Comment: With only javascript this is not possible. This question has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Comment: I think I have my answer over all though now. Prior to asking I was coming up with mixed results via bing google other the community here is much more reliable so I figured my last ditch effort would be to ask a question i was 99% sure about the answer here so I can confidently say 100% instead. Thank you everyone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that said is it possible to actually write to a file and or get its contents via javascript with or without the help of a lib such as jquery?

Nope. You will need *something* running on server side that can receive your JavaScript input and write it to the server.

Internet Explorer's proprietary file writing functionality is for writing local (client-side) files only.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file using ajax, but without a server side language you cannot write a file to the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax

Answer (score 1):

No. Javascript runs on the client. You need server-side code to access the server's file system.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side JavaScript can only send data to a server, there's no way for it to tell the server what to do with the data.

To save data to a file or db on a server, you'll require a server-side script of some sort (*could* be server-side JS with Node.js). If all you need is persistent data, you could store some JSON strings in `localStorage` or in cookies as needed. They wouldn't be shareable that way though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AJAX requests in JavaScript without using jQuery. However, jQuery will save you an ungodly amount of time and cross-browser testing.

But, as others have already said, you can't write server files without server code.